# haproxy acl hdr seems inoperant

Tags: linux, haproxy

Using haproxy, I try to add a Content-Security-Policy header except for Safari client that do not handle this header.
I try to use an acl with *req.hdr(User-Agent)* to detect a iPhone client.
I can't make it work : it seems to be inoperant thought I can log the User-Agent header in log file.

```
# uname -a
Linux arnaud 4.19.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.249-2 (2022-06-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# haproxy --version
HA-Proxy version 1.8.19-1+deb10u3 2020/08/01
Copyright 2000-2019 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>
```

I try the following configuration :

```
frontend fe_prod
    bind :10083
    mode http
    capture request  header User-Agent len 256
    acl iosUA req.fhdr(User-Agent) -m sub iPhone
    http-response add-header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' file://* filesystem:;" unless iosUA
    use_backend be_dev

backend be_dev
    mode http
    server dev 127.0.0.1:83
```

In the haproxy.log file, I can see :

```
May 17 10:28:46 arnaud haproxy[29442]: 127.0.0.1:52016 [17/May/2023:10:28:46.077] fe_prod be_dev/dev 0/0/0/2/2 304 183 - - ---- 6/6/0/1/0 0/0 {Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1} "GET /login HTTP/1.1"
```

But the HTTP response always include the Content-Security-Policy header, even for this User-Agent.
I already spent one full day dealing with different configurations, but cannot find what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/935492/haproxy-does-not-add-headers-conditionally).

I quote the explanation from [a comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/935492/haproxy-does-not-add-headers-conditionally#comment1213709_935495) by [@Michael-sqlbot](https://serverfault.com/users/153161/michael-sqlbot) on Oct 15, 2018:

> This answer is correct, but the further answer is no, ACLs do not work that way in HAProxy. ACLs are only evaluated at the point when they are tested, so in this case they would not be tested until during response processing... and the unqualified `hdr()` fetch assumes response header at that point... but if you qualify it as `req.hdr()` that does not change the expected behavior because the buffer holding request headers has already been released by then, so request fetches have nothing to search. The txn variables persist from request to response.